# Count number of lines with javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need to trim a dynamic text in order to make a 2 lines excerpt out of it (a teaser).
The problem is that the number of lines that takes a displayed string within a div depends on the characters used (for instance,"w" and i" will not have the same width), the browser and the OS (a font on Mac is not exactly equal to the same font on Windows).

Is there a way, in javascript, to trim a text that would be longer than x lines within a div (knowing that the div length is fixed)?

Thank you.

Comment: So, you're **not** looking specifically for newline characters, but rather the amount of text that will **reflow** into a given div?

Comment: How about using CSS' text overflow properties instead of measuring stuff with JavaScript (which is inevitably messy)?

Comment: What would the css "overflow" property do as I need to cut the text right before it reaches the third line and add something like "read more"? Thank you

Comment: @sarnold: I'm sorry, I don't get your question. What I need is to cut the text within the div in order to keep the first two lines of it. As the text would be generated, I can't predict its content so I can't predict its exact lenght. Have a look at my question here above. Imagine I want to keep the first two lines and add "Read more" just after. Is it clear enough? Thank you.

Comment: You might get pretty close by using HTML5 Canvas `measureText()`; keep adding words until you surpass the width of your container, and do that again for a second line.

Answer (score 4):

you can use something like that http://jsfiddle.net/cSTzn/ by using `overflow: hidden;` and proper `height`

EDIT: made update with link on the bottom right, customize as necessary http://jsfiddle.net/cSTzn/1/

Comment: Though the downside is the hidden text isn't hidden very well -- and still easily selectable. (Which isn't a big deal if it is all short... if it is going to be _huge_, perhaps it shouldn't be downloaded at all...?)

Comment: Thank you but it's not what I need. I want to create an excerpt. A kind of teaser of a larger text by keeping the first two lines of the text and allow the user to click a link to see the whole content. It's something very usual on Wordpress for instance. It's not about "hiding" visually the right or bottom part of a text. Css Will not help on this issue. Thank you.

Comment: I really thank you for your help. You solution is almost ok but you can see the problem with it: the text behind the "read more" is not readable. My ultimate goal would be to end the second line with: "whatever is the end of the second line....(read more)". Is there no javascript functions which would allow me to know which words are ending the second line and delete whatever is after?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to calculate the end of the 2nd line, if you can use font that is fixed size then it is doable, otherwise you have to trim and check the hight of the container and the height of the content while trimming and stop when the content fits, but I already don't like that solution

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there is no web font having a fixed size and being cross-browser and cross-OS. Strange as these "teasers/excerpts" can be found very often in modern content management systems nowadays. I really don't know how they achieve this...

Comment: I had a look. Thank you for your effort. The problem is that monospace means that according to your plateform, the system will use a font which has the same lenght for each letter WITHIN your OS but it doesn't mean the font (thus the relative lenght) will be the same on the other OS's. So I can create a php function to truncate the text according to the number of letters that would fit two lines but If I do so by taking a Mac as a reference, it will be different on a Windows or on a Linux, not to mention which monospace fonts are installed on the system. Not ideal.

Comment: Just to make sure we are on the same page: here is a link that shows you want I'm looking for: Each headline is three lines long (never more). The text is truncated and ends with "... more>>". [news.yahoo.com](http://news.yahoo.com/)

Comment: in that case they use variable length and after running through ton of tests they have come to a range that puts the truncated text on the 3rd line, you can copy what they have done, however as you can see it is not perfectly filling the 3 lines, sometime it is in the very beginning, but it is definitely doable, good luck